# Meaning of PropertyAttributes.HasDefault and PropertyBuilder.SetConstant

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil, reflection.emit

I would like to ask what is the purpose of `PropertyAttribute.HasDefault` enum value in context of defining property using `System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.DefineProperty` method? When one should use `PropertyAttributes.HasDefault` and when `PropertyAttributes.None` and what does it change?

As far as I can see it's related to SetConstant method of PropertyBuilder but it doesn't really change default value of property as far as I was able to test, so what does SetConstant really do?

(I don't intent to change property's default value - just trying to understand what these things do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetConstant` is a wrapper around `TypeBuilder.SetConstantValue()`, which is used to associate compile-time constants with certain IL metadata, most commonly parameters (with default values) and `const` fields.

Its usefulness for properties seems rather dubious; it does not affect what value is actually returned by the property's `get` accessor.  It would seem the default value set via `SetConstant()` can only be inspected in the metadata or via reflection.  It might be useful if you want to allow someone to determine the default value returned by a property using reflection or IL analysis only, but since the `get` accessor is not required to actually return that value, ever, it should be taken with a grain of salt.